# Understanding the Use of ColorMatrix and ColorMatrixColorFilter to Modify a Drawable's Hue

Tags: android, drawable, colormatrix, colorfilter

I'm working on a UI for an app, and I'm attempting to use grayscale icons, and allow the user to change the theme to a color of their choosing. To do this, I'm trying to just apply a ColorFilter of some sort to overlay a color on top of the drawable. I've tried using PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY, and it works almost exactly as I need, except that whites get overlayed with the color as well. What I'm ideally looking for is something like the "Color" blending mode in Photoshop, where the graphic retains its transparency and luminosity, and only modifies the color of the image. For example:
[image] becomes [image]
After doing some research, it appears that the ColorMatrixColorFilter class may do what I need, but I can't seem to find any resources pointing to how the matrix is used. It's a 4x5 matrix, but what I need to know is how I go about designing the matrix. Any ideas?

EDIT: So okay, what I've found so far on this is as follows:

```
1 0 0 0 0 //red
0 1 0 0 0 //green
0 0 1 0 0 //blue
0 0 0 1 0 //alpha
```

Where this matrix is the identity matrix (when applied, makes no changes), and the numbers range from 0 to 1 (floats). This matrix will be multiplied with each pixel to convert to the new color. So this is where it starts to get fuzzy for me. So I would think each pixel would be a 1 x 4 vector containing the argb values (e.g. `0.2, 0.5, 0.8, 1`) that would be dotted with the transformation matrix. So to double the red intensity of an image, you would use a matrix such as:

```
2 0 0 0 0 
0 1 0 0 0 
0 0 1 0 0 
0 0 0 1 0
```

which would give you a vector (color) of `0.4, 0.5, 0.8, 1`. From limited testing, this seems to be the case, and works properly, but I actually still end up with the same problem (i.e. whites gain coloring). Further reading tells me that this is because it's doing the conversion on RGB values, whereas for hue shifting, the values should first be converted to HSL values. So possibly I could write a class that would read the image and convert the colors, and redraw the image with the new colors. This creates ANOTHER problem with StateListDrawables, as I'm not sure how I would go about getting each of these in code and modifying all of them, and how slow a process it would be. :/

Hmm, okay, so I suppose another question I would have is whether a matrix can be used to convert RGB to another color space with luminosity information, such as L*a*b or HSL? If so, I could just multiply the matrix for that converstion, then make the hue adjustment to THAT matrix, then apply that matrix as the ColorFilter.

Comment: The best article I found on this subject is here: http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/effects/manipulate-visual-effects-with-the-colormatrixfilter-and-convolutionfilter/comment-page-1/#comment-45378

Answer (score 80, accepted):

This is what I use for my game. This is the compilation of various part found on various articles on websites. Credits goes to the original author from the @see links.
Note that a lot more can be done with color matrices. Including inverting, etc...

```
public class ColorFilterGenerator
{
    /**
 * Creates a HUE ajustment ColorFilter
 * @see http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/9e215c83c3819953
 * @see http://gskinner.com/blog/archives/2007/12/colormatrix_cla.html
 * @param value degrees to shift the hue.
 * @return
 */
public static ColorFilter adjustHue( float value )
{
    ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix();

    adjustHue(cm, value);

    return new ColorMatrixColorFilter(cm);
}

/**
 * @see http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/9e215c83c3819953
 * @see http://gskinner.com/blog/archives/2007/12/colormatrix_cla.html
 * @param cm
 * @param value
 */
public static void adjustHue(ColorMatrix cm, float value)
{
    value = cleanValue(value, 180f) / 180f * (float) Math.PI;
    if (value == 0)
    {
        return;
    }
    float cosVal = (float) Math.cos(value);
    float sinVal = (float) Math.sin(value);
    float lumR = 0.213f;
    float lumG = 0.715f;
    float lumB = 0.072f;
    float[] mat = new float[]
    { 
            lumR + cosVal * (1 - lumR) + sinVal * (-lumR), lumG + cosVal * (-lumG) + sinVal * (-lumG), lumB + cosVal * (-lumB) + sinVal * (1 - lumB), 0, 0, 
            lumR + cosVal * (-lumR) + sinVal * (0.143f), lumG + cosVal * (1 - lumG) + sinVal * (0.140f), lumB + cosVal * (-lumB) + sinVal * (-0.283f), 0, 0,
            lumR + cosVal * (-lumR) + sinVal * (-(1 - lumR)), lumG + cosVal * (-lumG) + sinVal * (lumG), lumB + cosVal * (1 - lumB) + sinVal * (lumB), 0, 0, 
            0f, 0f, 0f, 1f, 0f, 
            0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1f };
    cm.postConcat(new ColorMatrix(mat));
}

protected static float cleanValue(float p_val, float p_limit)
{
    return Math.min(p_limit, Math.max(-p_limit, p_val));
}
}
```

To complete this I should add an example:

```
ImageView Sun = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.sun);
Sun.setColorFilter(ColorFilterGenerator.adjustHue(162)); // 162 degree rotation
```

Comment: Wow, thanks! I'm not going to pretend I understand exactly what's going on with those matrix values, but I'm curious, what does the `cleanValue()` method do?

Comment: it makes sure it doesn't go out of bound and cause artifacts.

Comment: @RichardLalancette Can you explain why the matrix `mat` in your code has 5 rows? Shouldn't it be 4 rows only (one for each R G B A)?

Comment: @RichardLalancette OK I got it, it is to allow the matrix concatenation, isn't it? Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @RichardLalancette After looking at the source code of `ColorMatrix`, I take it back. The last row in `mat` is never used at all. The `ColorMatrix` constructor only takes the first 4 rows (copies the first 20 floats of the given source matrix).

Comment: I revisited one of the links and found that the last column is actually an offset. See Here's How it Works on the following link: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/manipulate-visual-effects-with-the-colormatrixfilter-and-convolutionfilter--active-3221#comment-45378

Comment: Also, I think the original source of the code was wrong. The 5th row can probably be taken out since the class really only needs 4 according to the documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ColorMatrix.html. I do not have the project at hand so if someone is willing to test without the last row, please share the results back here.

Comment: I just tested it without the 5th row and the results seem to be the same.

Comment: Sweet Miguel. Thanks for updating us.

Comment: I tired your code, by making same class and setColorFilter as you mention. But nothing works for me. My image is still same :(

Comment: I was tried it on Transparent Image that's why image color not change but when I tried it on a Red Image its color convert into Green. So, Is it not work in case of Transparent Image ? And why you pass exactly "162" in method of Adjust hue ?

Comment: 162 is the number of degrees for a given hue rotation.  You should adjust this number to fit your needs.

Comment: How would you factor in an existing color into that example above let's say you want to generate a ColorFilter for the color, #FF6600 with a hue of 110?

Comment: Can you please mention any documents for better understanding the numbers and formula you have been used? thannks

Comment: what are 
    float lumR = 0.213f;
    float lumG = 0.715f;
    float lumB = 0.072f; and why have you chosen those values ?

Answer (score 51):

here is the complete code if you want to adjust the bright, contrast, saturation and hue. Enjoy!
Thanks a lot to @RichardLalancette

```
public class ColorFilterGenerator {

private static double DELTA_INDEX[] = {
    0,    0.01, 0.02, 0.04, 0.05, 0.06, 0.07, 0.08, 0.1,  0.11,
    0.12, 0.14, 0.15, 0.16, 0.17, 0.18, 0.20, 0.21, 0.22, 0.24,
    0.25, 0.27, 0.28, 0.30, 0.32, 0.34, 0.36, 0.38, 0.40, 0.42,
    0.44, 0.46, 0.48, 0.5,  0.53, 0.56, 0.59, 0.62, 0.65, 0.68, 
    0.71, 0.74, 0.77, 0.80, 0.83, 0.86, 0.89, 0.92, 0.95, 0.98,
    1.0,  1.06, 1.12, 1.18, 1.24, 1.30, 1.36, 1.42, 1.48, 1.54,
    1.60, 1.66, 1.72, 1.78, 1.84, 1.90, 1.96, 2.0,  2.12, 2.25, 
    2.37, 2.50, 2.62, 2.75, 2.87, 3.0,  3.2,  3.4,  3.6,  3.8,
    4.0,  4.3,  4.7,  4.9,  5.0,  5.5,  6.0,  6.5,  6.8,  7.0,
    7.3,  7.5,  7.8,  8.0,  8.4,  8.7,  9.0,  9.4,  9.6,  9.8, 
    10.0
};

/**
 * @see http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/9e215c83c3819953
 * @see http://gskinner.com/blog/archives/2007/12/colormatrix_cla.html
 * @param cm
 * @param value
 */
public static void adjustHue(ColorMatrix cm, float value)
{
    value = cleanValue(value, 180f) / 180f * (float) Math.PI;
    if (value == 0){
        return;
    }

    float cosVal = (float) Math.cos(value);
    float sinVal = (float) Math.sin(value);
    float lumR = 0.213f;
    float lumG = 0.715f;
    float lumB = 0.072f;
    float[] mat = new float[]
    { 
            lumR + cosVal * (1 - lumR) + sinVal * (-lumR), lumG + cosVal * (-lumG) + sinVal * (-lumG), lumB + cosVal * (-lumB) + sinVal * (1 - lumB), 0, 0, 
            lumR + cosVal * (-lumR) + sinVal * (0.143f), lumG + cosVal * (1 - lumG) + sinVal * (0.140f), lumB + cosVal * (-lumB) + sinVal * (-0.283f), 0, 0,
            lumR + cosVal * (-lumR) + sinVal * (-(1 - lumR)), lumG + cosVal * (-lumG) + sinVal * (lumG), lumB + cosVal * (1 - lumB) + sinVal * (lumB), 0, 0, 
            0f, 0f, 0f, 1f, 0f, 
            0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1f };
    cm.postConcat(new ColorMatrix(mat));
}

public static void adjustBrightness(ColorMatrix cm, float value) {
    value = cleanValue(value,100);
    if (value == 0) {
        return;
    }

    float[] mat = new float[]
    { 
        1,0,0,0,value,
        0,1,0,0,value,
        0,0,1,0,value,
        0,0,0,1,0,
        0,0,0,0,1
    };
    cm.postConcat(new ColorMatrix(mat));
}

public static void adjustContrast(ColorMatrix cm, int value) {
    value = (int)cleanValue(value,100);
    if (value == 0) { 
        return; 
    }
    float x;
    if (value < 0) {
        x = 127 + (float) value / 100*127;
    } else {
        x = value % 1;
        if (x == 0) {
            x = (float)DELTA_INDEX[value];
        } else {
            //x = DELTA_INDEX[(p_val<<0)]; // this is how the IDE does it.
            x = (float)DELTA_INDEX[(value<<0)]*(1-x) + (float)DELTA_INDEX[(value<<0)+1] * x; // use linear interpolation for more granularity.
        }
        x = x*127+127;
    }

    float[] mat = new float[]
    { 
            x/127,0,0,0, 0.5f*(127-x),
            0,x/127,0,0, 0.5f*(127-x),
            0,0,x/127,0, 0.5f*(127-x),
            0,0,0,1,0,
            0,0,0,0,1
    };
    cm.postConcat(new ColorMatrix(mat));

}

public static void adjustSaturation(ColorMatrix cm, float value) {
    value = cleanValue(value,100);
    if (value == 0) {
        return;
    }

    float x = 1+((value > 0) ? 3 * value / 100 : value / 100);
    float lumR = 0.3086f;
    float lumG = 0.6094f;
    float lumB = 0.0820f;

    float[] mat = new float[]
    { 
        lumR*(1-x)+x,lumG*(1-x),lumB*(1-x),0,0,
        lumR*(1-x),lumG*(1-x)+x,lumB*(1-x),0,0,
        lumR*(1-x),lumG*(1-x),lumB*(1-x)+x,0,0,
        0,0,0,1,0,
        0,0,0,0,1
    };
    cm.postConcat(new ColorMatrix(mat));
}



protected static float cleanValue(float p_val, float p_limit)
{
    return Math.min(p_limit, Math.max(-p_limit, p_val));
}

public static ColorFilter adjustColor(int brightness, int contrast, int saturation, int hue){
    ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix();
    adjustHue(cm, hue);
    adjustContrast(cm, contrast);
    adjustBrightness(cm, brightness);
    adjustSaturation(cm, saturation);

    return new ColorMatrixColorFilter(cm);
}
}
```

Comment: Is it available to change saturation for only one color (blue)?

Comment: "value<<0" is the same as "value"

Comment: Thanks for a valuable code. Two comments regarding your `adjustContrast` method: **(1)** the expression `value<<0` seems redundant, as it would always be equal to (just) `value`.   **(2)** As `value` is an integer, wouldn't `value % 1` be always equal to 0?

Comment: The possbile value range for brightness is wrong. It should be between -255 and 255 or converted afterwards.

Answer (score 13):

For anyone who is interested in how to use the ColorMatrixColorFilter. The sample I used here, converted every pixel into red when I draw the bitmap on the canvas.

The comment in the class is from: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ColorMatrix.html this gives you some insights on how this is working

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    // The matrix is stored in a single array, and its treated as follows: [ a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t ]
    // When applied to a color [r, g, b, a], the resulting color is computed as (after clamping) ;
    //   R' = a*R + b*G + c*B + d*A + e; 
    //   G' = f*R + g*G + h*B + i*A + j; 
    //   B' = k*R + l*G + m*B + n*A + o; 
    //   A' = p*R + q*G + r*B + s*A + t; 

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    float[] matrix = { 
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, //red
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, //green
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, //blue
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1 //alpha
    };
    paint.setColorFilter(new ColorMatrixColorFilter(matrix));

    Rect source = new Rect(0, 0, 100, 100);
    Rect dest = new Rect(0, 0, 100, 100);

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.sampleimage);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap , source, dest, paint);
}
```

Comment: Your code worked perfectly for my case, where I needed to colour some PNGs: https://gist.github.com/puelocesar/9710910 - Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

The below class is an improvement on the answers that have already been posted. This makes it easier to read and create a `ColorFilter` from a `Bitmap`.

Example usage:

```
ImageView imageView = ...;
Drawable drawable = imageView.getDrawable();
ColorFilter colorFilter = ColorFilterGenerator.from(drawable).to(Color.RED);
imageView.setColorFilter(colorFilter);
```

---

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.ColorFilter;
import android.graphics.ColorMatrix;
import android.graphics.ColorMatrixColorFilter;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.PictureDrawable;
import android.widget.ImageView;

/**
 * Creates a {@link ColorMatrixColorFilter} to adjust the hue, saturation, brightness, or
 * contrast of an {@link Bitmap}, {@link Drawable}, or {@link ImageView}.
 * <p/>
 * Example usage:
 * <br/>
 * {@code imageView.setColorFilter(ColorFilterGenerator.from(Color.BLUE).to(Color.RED));}
 *
 * @author Jared Rummler <jared.rummler@gmail.com>
 */
public class ColorFilterGenerator {

  // Based off answer from StackOverflow
  // See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15119089/1048340

  private ColorFilterGenerator() {
    throw new AssertionError();
  }

  public static From from(Drawable drawable) {
    return new From(drawableToBitmap(drawable));
  }

  public static From from(Bitmap bitmap) {
    return new From(bitmap);
  }

  public static From from(int color) {
    return new From(color);
  }

  // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  private static final double DELTA_INDEX[] = {
      0, 0.01, 0.02, 0.04, 0.05, 0.06, 0.07, 0.08, 0.1, 0.11, 0.12, 0.14, 0.15, 0.16, 0.17, 0.18,
      0.20, 0.21, 0.22, 0.24, 0.25, 0.27, 0.28, 0.30, 0.32, 0.34, 0.36, 0.38, 0.40, 0.42, 0.44,
      0.46, 0.48, 0.5, 0.53, 0.56, 0.59, 0.62, 0.65, 0.68, 0.71, 0.74, 0.77, 0.80, 0.83, 0.86, 0.89,
      0.92, 0.95, 0.98, 1.0, 1.06, 1.12, 1.18, 1.24, 1.30, 1.36, 1.42, 1.48, 1.54, 1.60, 1.66, 1.72,
      1.78, 1.84, 1.90, 1.96, 2.0, 2.12, 2.25, 2.37, 2.50, 2.62, 2.75, 2.87, 3.0, 3.2, 3.4, 3.6,
      3.8, 4.0, 4.3, 4.7, 4.9, 5.0, 5.5, 6.0, 6.5, 6.8, 7.0, 7.3, 7.5, 7.8, 8.0, 8.4, 8.7, 9.0, 9.4,
      9.6, 9.8, 10.0
  };

  public static void adjustHue(ColorMatrix cm, float value) {
    value = cleanValue(value, 180f) / 180f * (float) Math.PI;
    if (value == 0) {
      return;
    }

    float cosVal = (float) Math.cos(value);
    float sinVal = (float) Math.sin(value);
    float lumR = 0.213f;
    float lumG = 0.715f;
    float lumB = 0.072f;
    float[] mat = new float[]{
        lumR + cosVal * (1 - lumR) + sinVal * (-lumR),
        lumG + cosVal * (-lumG) + sinVal * (-lumG),
        lumB + cosVal * (-lumB) + sinVal * (1 - lumB), 0, 0,
        lumR + cosVal * (-lumR) + sinVal * (0.143f),
        lumG + cosVal * (1 - lumG) + sinVal * (0.140f),
        lumB + cosVal * (-lumB) + sinVal * (-0.283f), 0, 0,
        lumR + cosVal * (-lumR) + sinVal * (-(1 - lumR)),
        lumG + cosVal * (-lumG) + sinVal * (lumG),
        lumB + cosVal * (1 - lumB) + sinVal * (lumB), 0, 0, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f,
        0f, 1f
    };
    cm.postConcat(new ColorMatrix(mat));
  }

  public static void adjustBrightness(ColorMatrix cm, float value) {
    value = cleanValue(value, 100);
    if (value == 0) {
      return;
    }

    float[] mat = new float[]{
        1, 0, 0, 0, value, 0, 1, 0, 0, value, 0, 0, 1, 0, value, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        1
    };
    cm.postConcat(new ColorMatrix(mat));
  }

  public static void adjustContrast(ColorMatrix cm, int value) {
    value = (int) cleanValue(value, 100);
    if (value == 0) {
      return;
    }
    float x;
    if (value < 0) {
      x = 127 + value / 100 * 127;
    } else {
      x = value % 1;
      if (x == 0) {
        x = (float) DELTA_INDEX[value];
      } else {
        x = (float) DELTA_INDEX[(value << 0)] * (1 - x)
            + (float) DELTA_INDEX[(value << 0) + 1] * x;
      }
      x = x * 127 + 127;
    }

    float[] mat = new float[]{
        x / 127, 0, 0, 0, 0.5f * (127 - x), 0, x / 127, 0, 0, 0.5f * (127 - x), 0, 0,
        x / 127, 0, 0.5f * (127 - x), 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1
    };
    cm.postConcat(new ColorMatrix(mat));

  }

  public static void adjustSaturation(ColorMatrix cm, float value) {
    value = cleanValue(value, 100);
    if (value == 0) {
      return;
    }

    float x = 1 + ((value > 0) ? 3 * value / 100 : value / 100);
    float lumR = 0.3086f;
    float lumG = 0.6094f;
    float lumB = 0.0820f;

    float[] mat = new float[]{
        lumR * (1 - x) + x, lumG * (1 - x), lumB * (1 - x), 0, 0, lumR * (1 - x),
        lumG * (1 - x) + x, lumB * (1 - x), 0, 0, lumR * (1 - x), lumG * (1 - x),
        lumB * (1 - x) + x, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1
    };
    cm.postConcat(new ColorMatrix(mat));
  }

  // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  private static float cleanValue(float p_val, float p_limit) {
    return Math.min(p_limit, Math.max(-p_limit, p_val));
  }

  private static float[] getHsv(int color) {
    float[] hsv = new float[3];
    Color.RGBToHSV(Color.red(color), Color.green(color), Color.blue(color), hsv);
    return hsv;
  }

  /**
   * Converts a {@link Drawable} to a {@link Bitmap}
   *
   * @param drawable
   *     The {@link Drawable} to convert
   * @return The converted {@link Bitmap}.
   */
  private static Bitmap drawableToBitmap(Drawable drawable) {
    if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
      return ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
    } else if (drawable instanceof PictureDrawable) {
      PictureDrawable pictureDrawable = (PictureDrawable) drawable;
      Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(pictureDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(),
          pictureDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
      Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
      canvas.drawPicture(pictureDrawable.getPicture());
      return bitmap;
    }
    int width = drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
    width = width > 0 ? width : 1;
    int height = drawable.getIntrinsicHeight();
    height = height > 0 ? height : 1;
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    drawable.draw(canvas);
    return bitmap;
  }

  /**
   * Calculate the average red, green, blue color values of a bitmap
   *
   * @param bitmap
   *     a {@link Bitmap}
   * @return
   */
  private static int[] getAverageColorRGB(Bitmap bitmap) {
    int width = bitmap.getWidth();
    int height = bitmap.getHeight();
    int size = width * height;
    int[] pixels = new int[size];
    int r, g, b;
    r = g = b = 0;
    bitmap.getPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      int pixelColor = pixels[i];
      if (pixelColor == Color.TRANSPARENT) {
        size--;
        continue;
      }
      r += Color.red(pixelColor);
      g += Color.green(pixelColor);
      b += Color.blue(pixelColor);
    }
    r /= size;
    g /= size;
    b /= size;
    return new int[]{
        r, g, b
    };
  }

  /**
   * Calculate the average color value of a bitmap
   *
   * @param bitmap
   *     a {@link Bitmap}
   * @return
   */
  private static int getAverageColor(Bitmap bitmap) {
    int[] rgb = getAverageColorRGB(bitmap);
    return Color.argb(255, rgb[0], rgb[1], rgb[2]);
  }

  // Builder
  // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  public static final class Builder {

    int hue;

    int contrast;

    int brightness;

    int saturation;

    public Builder setHue(int hue) {
      this.hue = hue;
      return this;
    }

    public Builder setContrast(int contrast) {
      this.contrast = contrast;
      return this;
    }

    public Builder setBrightness(int brightness) {
      this.brightness = brightness;
      return this;
    }

    public Builder setSaturation(int saturation) {
      this.saturation = saturation;
      return this;
    }

    public ColorFilter build() {
      ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix();
      adjustHue(cm, hue);
      adjustContrast(cm, contrast);
      adjustBrightness(cm, brightness);
      adjustSaturation(cm, saturation);
      return new ColorMatrixColorFilter(cm);
    }
  }

  public static final class From {

    final int oldColor;

    private From(Bitmap bitmap) {
      oldColor = getAverageColor(bitmap);
    }

    private From(int oldColor) {
      this.oldColor = oldColor;
    }

    public ColorFilter to(int newColor) {
      float[] hsv1 = getHsv(oldColor);
      float[] hsv2 = getHsv(newColor);
      int hue = (int) (hsv2[0] - hsv1[0]);
      int saturation = (int) (hsv2[1] - hsv1[1]);
      int brightness = (int) (hsv2[2] - hsv1[2]);
      return new ColorFilterGenerator.Builder()
          .setHue(hue)
          .setSaturation(saturation)
          .setBrightness(brightness)
          .build();
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 8):

There is no linear relationship between Hue and RGB. Hue is defined piecewise in 60° chunks (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_color_space#General_approach), and therefore there is not a simple matrix conversion between HSV and RGB.
To change the hue of an image, you can use the following method :

```
public Bitmap changeHue( Bitmap source, double hue ) {
    Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap( source.getWidth(), source.getHeight(), source.getConfig() );

    float[] hsv = new float[3];
    for( int x = 0; x < source.getWidth(); x++ ) {
        for( int y = 0; y < source.getHeight(); y++ ) {
            int c = source.getPixel( x, y );
            Color.colorToHSV( c, hsv );
            hsv[0] = (float) ((hsv[0] + 360 * hue) % 360);
            c = (Color.HSVToColor( hsv ) & 0x00ffffff) | (c & 0xff000000);
            result.setPixel( x, y, c );
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I think this method will give you what you want:

http://android.okhelp.cz/hue-color-colored-filter-bitmap-image-android-example/

```
bitmapOrg.setColorFilter(Color.RED, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

Comment: To note, this method will not change the hue in the same way as the ColorFilterGenerator methods shown above. To see what it may produce open your bitmap in Photoshop or GIMP. Create a layer over top of the image and fill it with your desired color. Then set the layer mode of the overlay to multiply. Se the layer mode to hue to preview what the ColorFilterGenerator methods will do.

Answer (score 7):

Like the rest of the answers I used a color matrix to implement this behavior, but you can pass in a regular Android color resource. The matrix, maps the color into a range between the image value and white.

```
/**
 * Color everything that isn't white, the tint color
 * @param tintColor the color to tint the icon
 */
public void setInverseMultiplyFilter(Drawable imgCopy, @ColorInt int tintColor) {

    Drawable imgCopy = imageView.getDrawable().getConstantState().newDrawable();

    float colorRed = Color.red(tintColor) / 255f;
    float colorGreen = Color.green(tintColor) / 255f;
    float colorBlue = Color.blue(tintColor) / 255f;

    imgCopy.setColorFilter(new ColorMatrixColorFilter(new ColorMatrix(new float[]{
            1 - colorRed, 0,              0,             0,     colorRed * 255,
            0,            1 - colorGreen, 0,             0,     colorGreen * 255,
            0,            0,              1 - colorBlue, 0,     colorBlue * 255,
            0,            0,              0,             Color.alpha(tintColor) / 255f, 0,
    })));

    imageView.setImageDrawable(imgCopy);
    imageView.invalidate();
}
```

Comment: Hello Benjamin, by using above matrix can we tint everything except Green ?. And also can we combine more than one color to be preserved ? example preserve white and green, tint rest. Please your answer will help me

Answer (score 2):

I made a little ColorMatrixFilter tester, based on the following snippet:

```
private Bitmap setColorFilter(Bitmap drawable) {                
            Bitmap grayscale  = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getWidth(), drawable.getHeight(), drawable.getConfig());
            //if(isRenderMode) bOriginal.recycle();
            Canvas c = new Canvas(grayscale );
            Paint p = new Paint();

            final ColorMatrix matrixA = new ColorMatrix();
            matrixA.setSaturation(sauturationValue/2);


            float[] mx = {
                    r1Value,  r2Value,  r3Value,  r4Value,  r5Value,
                    g1Value,  g2Value,  g3Value,  g4Value,  g5Value,
                    b1Value,  b2Value,  b3Value,  b4Value,  b5Value,
                    a1Value,  a2Value,  a3Value,  a4Value,  a5Value
                    };
                    final ColorMatrix matrixB = new ColorMatrix(mx);

            matrixA.setConcat(matrixB, matrixA);

            final ColorMatrixColorFilter filter = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(matrixA);
            p.setColorFilter(filter);
            c.drawBitmap(drawable, 0, 0, p);
            return grayscale;               
        }
```

You can check it out here:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.vaelostudio.colormatrixtester

Answer (score 1):

Even though a lot of useful effects can be achieved by using the `ColorMatrix` I personally would consider using a `ColorMap[]` along with `ImageAttributes`. By doing this we can define which colors should be replaced with which colors.

Comment: What's a `ColorMap`? I think there is no such class available in the standard java/ android libs.

Answer (score 1):

The way I solved it is to start with a gray scale image.

[original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2FMXQ.png) ---> [grayImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rfDkz.png)

you can do it easily in photoshop, or if you need to do it in code you can use the following method.

```
private fun changeImageToGreyScale() {
   val matrix = ColorMatrix()
   matrix.setSaturation(0f)

   val originalBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, originalImageID)
   val bitmapCopy = Bitmap.createBitmap(originalBitmap.width, 
   originalBitmap.height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
   val canvas = Canvas(bitmapCopy)

   val paint = Paint()
   val colorFilter = ColorMatrixColorFilter(matrix)
   paint.colorFilter = colorFilter
   canvas.drawBitmap(originalBitmap, 0f, 0f, paint)
   grayScaleImage = bitmapCopy
}
```

After you have your GrayScale image you can use the PorterDuff OVERLAY mode to add the desired Color.

```
private fun applyFilterToImage() {

    val bitmapCopy = Bitmap.createBitmap(grayScaleImage.width, grayScaleImage.height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
    val canvas = Canvas(bitmapCopy)

    val rnd = java.util.Random()
    val randomColor = Color.rgb(rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256))

    val paint = Paint()
    val porterDuffMode = PorterDuff.Mode.OVERLAY
    paint.colorFilter = PorterDuffColorFilter(randomColor, porterDuffMode)

    val maskPaint = Paint()
    maskPaint. xfermode = PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_ATOP)

    canvas.drawBitmap(grayScaleImage, 0f, 0f, paint) 

    /**
    Note OVERLAY will disregard the alpha channel and will turn transparent 
    pixels into the randomColor. To resolve this I clip out that transparent area by 
    drawing the image again with the DST_ATOP XferMode
    **/
    canvas.drawBitmap(grayScaleImage, 0f, 0f, maskPaint)

    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmapCopy)
}
```

The above result is as follows
[randomColorGif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZWYW.gif)

Answer (score 0):

For supporting a full 360 degrees hue, I changed the following line in the accepted answer:

from:

```
value = cleanValue(value, 180f) / 180f * (float) Math.PI;
```

to:

```
value = cleanValue(value, 360f) / 360f * (float) Math.PI * 2;
```