# Android color overlay - PorterDuff modes

Tags: android, porter-duff, colorfilter

I have a black & white ninepatch drawable as background of a view and I would like to apply a color on it, like a semi-transparent overlay that leaves the drawing visible but applies the desired color on it.

I thought `drawable.setColorFilter(color,mode)` might do the trick, but I can't figure out what the different modes mean.

Could anyone give me a hint?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe this question may help you:

[Understanding the Use of ColorMatrix and ColorMatrixColorFilter to Modify a Drawable's Hue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4354939/understanding-the-use-of-colormatrix-and-colormatrixcolorfilter-to-modify-a-draw)

That said, I would suggest using `PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY`for what you're needing.

Comment: You're welcome! :) If you've used Photoshop blending modes (GIMP probably has something similar) there's a lot of overlap, and they work more or less the same way.

Comment: Is there a way to do this so that if the effect is applied multiple times it does not change the tint beyond the first draw? The image becomes more and more red for example...