# Bitmap Shader with alpha channel. (Alpha is drawing black..?)

Tags: android, colors, bitmap, drawing, alpha

I get my bitmap, use it as a shader tile mode.

The PNG is mostly alpha except for the shape outline to draw.

Except it draws the outline, but is surrounded by black, not seethrough (alpha).

```
    pnt.reset();

    if(backgroundColor == 1)
    {   
            pnt.setColor(myColor);
            pnt.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

    }

     m_canvas.drawPath(path, pnt);

//fillBMP = getBitmapFromAsset(m_context, "brush.png"); 
    fillBMP = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mySDPath + "brush.png");
fillBMPshader = new BitmapShader(fillBMP, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);  

pnt.setShader(fillBMPshader);  

m_canvas.drawPath(path, pnt);
```

Example below of the brush on left. But result it draws on right.

[image]

Comment: can u add `getBitmapFromAsset` method?

Comment: @userSeven7s Same direct from file. See edit to reflect. I've also just added Options for ARGB_8888 mode (which is default anyway), just to make sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set `XferMode` on your `Paint` object. More specifically you got to use [PorterDuffXferMode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PorterDuffXfermode.html) MULTIPLY.

Here is a similar question : [Android color overlay - PorterDuff modes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8139555/android-color-overlay-porterduff-modes)

Comment: Dont suppose you have an example and/or explaination please? :)

Comment: Seems to have done the trick, but now alternates between white and clear on each canvas draw. I think its a seperate issue though.

Comment: This isnt a good solution. Its having very bad effcts. Looking at http://softwyer.files.wordpress.com/2012/01/porterduffmodes.png , the one I want is `SrcOver` which is the default. Its just not taking into account the alpha.. With a simple game drawing loop. It is just white instead of alpha.

Comment: Tried with other constants of the porterduff.mode?

Comment: Ive tried with alsorts of them yea. It seems to work fine if I fill the shape with a colour before hand, then draw the brush over the top.. the alpha works. But not to anything before `paint.reset();` It just goes black. Where origionally a bitmap has been drawn on the canvas.

Comment: Lol, posting me editted code, I realise my first drawPath is outside teh if loop, which means its drawing without a color. So when there is no background it still draws over it with default color. Thanks man for your help!