# Animating color filter in Android

Tags: android, user-interface, animation, android-layout

Is there a standard solution or some implementation for creating **animations with color filter**? Specially, I would like to achieve a smooth highlighting animation using `LightingColorFilter`. I'll be thankful for any suggestions.

As far as I know, there is only alpha/rotate/scale/translate animation. How to implement this kind of animation easily? I am aiming Android 3.0 tablets (API 11).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you look at the [`ColorMatrix` Sample](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/ColorMatrixSample.html) in your API demos folder ? It seems that it animates a Bitmap exactly as you want.

However it's a bit more complicated to use than a `ColorFilter`. I found this SO question which explains how color matrix works (there may be an easier tutorial, but I didn't found anything) :

[Understanding the Use of ColorMatrix and ColorMatrixColorFilter to Modify a Drawable's Hue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4354939/understanding-the-use-of-colormatrix-and-colormatrixcolorfilter-to-modify-a-draw)

Comment: Thank you for great answer. I really missed this example. It looks like what I am looking for. But I'm not sure, if it is effective to use invalidate() in onDraw method. And it's a pity that I can't use animations object and interpolators with this.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to achieve an image glow before. What i did to circumvent the problem, was to create 2 images. One (in my case a ball without glow), and another including the glow. Using the alpha animation you mentioned, I was able to get an acceptable result for my case. Perhaps you can use something similar to achieve what you want.

Comment: Yes, this is a very tricky idea, can be easier to implement than the LadaRaider's solution and also using Interpolators. It just needs a little more work with graphics and prepare a reasonable layout.