# Custom LinearLayout

Tags: android, widget, android-linearlayout

I want to make layout like following :

[image]

For that i will need three backgrounds like this:

[image: This is one layout]

[image: this is another layout]

[image: this is another]

I will need to combine all of them and

at runtime i have to change background color of each

so i thought to make custom linearlayout.

But I don't know how to make it like that.

I have checked some example of making triangular and parallelogram layout but i want to merge all three views also. Please give some useful links and also give code example rather than giving references.

Thank you in Advance. :)

I tried in relative layout. for remoteview, i tried this:

```
ColorFilter cf = new PorterDuffColorFilter(-15032095, Mode.MULTIPLY);
        Drawable d= context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.panel1);
        d.mutate();
        d.setColorFilter(cf);
```

I tried below codes:

```
rv.setInt(R.id.rl_noti_main, "setColorFilter", d);
rv.setInt(R.id.rl_noti_main, "setBackgroundDrawable", -15032095);
rv.setInt(R.id.rl_noti_main, "setBackgroundResources",d);
```

Comment: instead of using images, you should make use of canvas and draw shapes over it using fill colors.

Comment: Thanks Amrut for reply. Can you suggest some code and also can you suggest  me how to draw?

Comment: Why don't you join these images vertically in photoshop and use it as background.

Comment: @Apurva: i can't do this as i have to change color of each runtime.

Comment: @kiturk3 I don't know any other way to do it. I also tried making using relativeLayout but it doesn't work

Comment: Can you post your relative layout also?

Answer (score 1):

try frame layout or relative layout. you need to overlap each view to achieve this which can't be done in linear layout. make each image as rectangle with transparent area which part need to overlap.

Comment: Hi @Sayem.... I tried with Relative Layout but problem is same... I have to change color of each view dynamically and there will be textview also on each views. :(

Comment: Use colorfilter to change color of image dynamically. If relative layout creates problem then try framelayot

Comment: i hgave done this:button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
  rl_1 = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.rl_1);
  button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Drawable d= getApplicationContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.panel_test1);
//    d.mutate();
//    d.setColorFilter(0xCC66FF, Mode.MULTIPLY);
    d.setColorFilter(new PorterDuffColorFilter(0xCC66FF, Mode.DARKEN));
//    d.setColorFilter(cf);
    rl_1.setBackground(d);
   }
  });

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1**

Consider making a custom view. You will extend the `View` class and override the `onDraw` method. In the `onDraw` method you will draw your special shapes. You can also make a method to set the colors of each part. Read the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html) first. It gives a pretty thorough overview. Then look for some tutorials about drawing and creating custom views. Follow along and by the time you are done you should be ready to try yourself.

Here are a couple tutorials that came up but I'm sure you can find more.

- [Android SDK: Creating Custom Views](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-creating-custom-views--mobile-14548)
- [Tutorial: Enhancing Android UI with Custom Views](https://thenewcircle.com/s/post/1663/tutorial_enhancing_android_ui_with_custom_views_dave_smith_video)

**Option 2**

Create your three shapes as white images (or maybe as [9-patch](http://radleymarx.com/blog/simple-guide-to-9-patch/) images depending on how you need them to resize for different layouts). The parts you don't want colored you can make transparent. I might even make the middle image as a tall rectangle (or even a simple rectangular View) and layer the other two images on top.) Then use a `RelativeLayout` to stack or overlap the images on each other. After that use `Drawable.setColorFilter` to change the color programmatically. See the links below. This seems to have been successful for a lot of people.

- [Modifying the color of an android drawable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9643603/modifying-the-color-of-an-android-drawable)
- [Applying ColorFilter to ImageView with ShapedDrawable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10114420/applying-colorfilter-to-imageview-with-shapeddrawable/10141607#10141607)
- [How to change colors of a Drawable in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309629/how-to-change-colors-of-a-drawable-in-android)

Comment: my first thought was doing the same you suggested but it may be time consuming and if there is no option other than that i have to use this solution only. :)

Comment: See my second option if you don't want to make a custom view.

Comment: yes but how to change color in remoteview as i mentioned that i want it for widget view

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do. Please update your question with more details about what exactly it is you want to accomplish.

Comment: I have already mentioned in question itself that i want to set this layout in widget and also want to change color dynamically.

Comment: I didn't see anything about widgets in your question, but widgets can use RelativeLayouts, too. You can change the color of the images dynamically with setColorFilter. Have you tried that yet? You can update your question with why that didn't work.

Comment: yup i tried relative layout. and updating question. ty :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73164/discussion-between-kiturk3-and-suragch).