# Change background color of remoteview dynamically

Tags: android, android-layout, remoteview

As of my previous question
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29025795/custom-linearlayout?noredirect=1#comment46419981_29025795)
I successfully managed to do this by transparent image. Now i want to change background color of images dynamically in remoteviews(PS I want to make widget like that and color of images in given link changes dynamically).

I tried following code:

```
ColorFilter cf = new PorterDuffColorFilter(-15032095, Mode.MULTIPLY);
        Drawable d= context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.panel1);
        d.mutate();
        d.setColorFilter(cf);
        rv.setBitmap(R.id.rl_noti_main, "setColorFilter", drawableToBitmap(d));
```

but it didn't help. How can i achieve this?
I have color codes in all formats integer, HEX or string whatever it will be needed.
Please note that i want to do this only for given shapes in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29025795/custom-linearlayout?noredirect=1#comment46419981_29025795) link and for remoteview.

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 4):

For someone else looking for it

```
remoteView.setInt(R.id.container, "setBackgroundColor", backgroundColor);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot dynamically update widgets.

You can use the [setBitmap() method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html#setBitmap(int,%20java.lang.String,%20android.graphics.Bitmap)) to change the bitmap of a view inside a `RemoteView`. If the view is at the background, it should change the background. And then update the widget to make the changes to be applied.

If you are using `RemoteViews` in Notifications, you should update your notification after this. If you are using it in a `Widget`, you should use `appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);` function.

Comment: Thanks tasomaniac.... I am using it in notifications. And seriously i didnt get you. can you explain in brief. I am using panel1 as drawable which resides in drawable folder and it is transparent.How to change color of that particular shape by code. i have tried rv.setInt(R.id.rl_main, "setBackgroundColor", -15032095) and many more.

Comment: You can put an ImageView as a background and change its src using `setBitmap` or `setImageViewBitmap` functions.

Comment: I will get color from color picker, so will it be possible?

Comment: and also i have to type texts inside the view so will this also be possible?

Comment: What do you mean type? With keyboard? Opening a keyboard is not possible. You can open an external Activity with an EditText inside with a keyboard. If you want to just change the text, there is also `setTextViewText` function inside RemoteViews.

Comment: obviously i am talking about setTextViewText. I am setting received notification in one of the view. user will able to change the theme (color of view) according to his/her wish. I dont need to open keyboard for that.