# How to Change color code of an image in android

Tags: android, image, colors

I am stuck in a problem in one of my application. What I have to do that I need to change the color of an existing image which is put in drawable through programatically and after changing the color set as a background in a relative layout.
The image whose color has to be changed is attached as below. Please have a look on it.
[image: This image is in horizontal rectangular shape and inclined portion of both the sides are transparent such that the rectangle looks like in inclined manner.]

This image is in horizontal rectangular shape and inclined portion of both the sides are transparent such that the rectangle looks like in inclined manner.

So, guys with the help of code how can i change the color of this particular image? Please help me to sort out this problem. Thanks !!!

Comment: see Drawable.setColorFilter() method

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9643603/modifying-the-color-of-an-android-drawable

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9643603/modifying-the-color-of-an-android-drawable