# create shadow for bitmap in custom view

Tags: android, bitmap, shadow

I have a custom view wich contain some bitmaps and I want to set shadows for them, for that, I use this code:

```
shadowPaints=new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
shadowPaints.setShadowLayer(10.0f, 3.0f, 2.0f, Color.BLACK);
canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, matrix, shadowPaints);   
setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, shadowPaints);
```

and my result is [image]
as you can see my shadow actually is another bitmap with different x and y position but what I want is my shadow be a solid color
bitmap.
can anyone help me about this?

Comment: Could you post all code of your custom view?

Comment: thanks for your attention. it's too huge in code but if you show me a way that work in simple custom view im sure it will work on my customview too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setShadowLayer` is actually meant for putting shadows on text.

If you already know the bitmap you want to draw, you can just add a shadow in PhotoShop and draw the bitmap and shadow all at once.

If you don't want to do that, you could make a shadow by making a copy of the image, [using a PorterDuff filter to make it all grey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9643603/modifying-the-color-of-an-android-drawable), [use Renderscript to blur the image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067955/fast-bitmap-blur-for-android-sdk), and draw it on the canvas at an x,y offset before drawing the actual image on top of it.

Personally, I think PhotoShop is a lot easier.