# Can provided Android SDK icons be set with color?

Tags: android, android-icons

Android SDK provides the following icons.

Is there a way to set a color to those .. and if possible, how to do so?

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/share_button"
        style="@style/IconNav"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_share"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bookmark_button"
        style="@style/IconNav"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_get"/>
```

[image]

**UPDATE**

After doing a complete refresh of the project, it turns out the `tint` attribute in Xml did the trick.

> *For the short answer*
>
> .. this is the solution that worked for me - adding the property to the ImageView xml:
>
> ```
>     android:tint="@color/grass_dark"
> ```

The answer from @goldenb is a thorough run through of the different ways to solve for this, so am marking that one as the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can indeed use a tint as a way of changing an `ImageView`'s colour, **BUT** you should be reminded that the `android:tint` will always be applied on top of the original colour.

as stated by blogger [danlew](http://blog.danlew.net/2014/08/18/fast-android-asset-theming-with-colorfilter/)

> - ImageView's tint mixes the tint color with the original asset. What you want is for the tint color to take over entirely; instead it
>     applies the tint on top of the existing color. So, for example, if the
>     source asset is black, and you want it to be #77FFFFFF (a translucent
>     shade of white), you'll actually end up getting that shade of white
>     with a black background beneath it.
> - android:tint is limited to ImageView. You want to be able to tint any Drawable in any View.

One possible alternative would be for you to use android [ColorFilter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ColorFilter.html)

According to the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ColorFilter.html):

> A color filter can be used with a Paint to modify the color of each pixel drawn with that paint. This is an abstract class that should never be used directly.

There are lots of more or less complex things you can do with ColorFilter but how can you apply this then?

One simple [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20121938/how-to-set-tint-for-an-image-view-programmatically-in-android) from another so question is:

```
//White tint
imageView.setColorFilter(Color.argb(255, 255, 255, 255)); 

or

imageView.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.COLOR_YOUR_COLOR))
```

Or a more complete answer here in SO from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10114420/applying-colorfilter-to-imageview-with-shapeddrawable)

```
ImageView redCircle = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.circle_red_imageview);
ImageView greenCircle = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.circle_green_imageview);
ImageView blueCircle = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.circle_blue_imageview);



// we can create the color values in different ways:
redCircle.getDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.RED, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY );
greenCircle.getDrawable().setColorFilter(0xff00ff00, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY );
blueCircle.getDrawable().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY );
```

You should check these links if you want to learn more

[SO - What is the difference between background, backgroundTint, backgroundTintMode attributes in android layout xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32471009/what-is-the-difference-between-background-backgroundtint-backgroundtintmode-at)

[setColorFilter()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setColorFilter%28int%2C%20android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode%29)

[Fast Android asset theming with ColorFilter](http://blog.danlew.net/2014/08/18/fast-android-asset-theming-with-colorfilter/)

[SO-Modifying the color of an android drawable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9855270/2819928)

Comment: @gnB have you been able to solve your problem? I believe this answer should be marked as correct , let me know if this helped =)

Comment: This solution setting the color in Java worked as well as using `android:tint`.  As with the other approach, I had to clean/refresh the project to get it to work.  Thank you for the pointer and details

Comment: @gnB my pleasure!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a bitmap with a tint. Add this to your drawables folder.

**ic_input_get_colored.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_get"
        android:tint="@color/yourDesiredColor"/>
```

Comment: This worked with an `<ImageView ../>` tag .  I had to clean/refresh the project to get it to work.

Comment: Wonderful. Best of luck.