# Using ColorMatrix to make an Image only black and white in Android

Tags: android

I am using below code to make an `ImageView` greyscale :

```
ColorMatrix colorMatrix = new ColorMatrix();
colorMatrix.setSaturation(0);
ColorMatrixColorFilter filter = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(colorMatrix);
imageView.setColorFilter(filter);
```

But I want to make it pure black and pure white, only two colors, not grey color.
How can I do this ?

Comment: checkout this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9643603/modifying-the-color-of-an-android-drawable

Comment: images could could have any color, but i want to map white to white and other colors to black