# Android - setColorFilter on Bitmap Doesn't Work

Tags: android, canvas, colors, bitmap

Is there a reason why the code below does not make any changes to the source bitmap mBitmap? mBitmap is a greyscale image that I would like to apply a color filter to. The filter itself is unimportant, but any color filter that I apply to it has no effect. What gets drawn to the screen is the original bitmap as though I applied no filter to it.

I can apply different color filters to it, such as:

```
mPaint.setColorFilter(new LightingColorFilter(Color.RED, 100));
```

But when I create a color filter from a color matrix, I get nothing.

I am using Android 2.3.

My Code:

```
float[] mat = new float[] {
        1f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1f,
        2f, 0f, 2f, 1f, 0f,
        1f, 1f, 0f, 0f, 0f,
        0f, 0f, 0f, 1f, 0f,
        2f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1f };

ColorMatrix colorMatrix = new ColorMatrix(mat);
ColorMatrixColorFilter colorFilter = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(colorMatrix);

mPaint.setColorFilter(colorFilter);

mCanvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
mCanvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mPaint);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apologies for asking this question. It was poorly formed due to my lack of understanding. for all I know that ColorMatrix above *actually does nothing*.

In short, my original problem stemmed from the fact that I was attempting to make a hue adjustment to a grayscale image. As it turns out: making a hue adjustment on a grayscale image has no meaning and therefore I was seeing no change.

The confusion came from this (excellent) question:

[Understanding the Use of ColorMatrix and ColorMatrixColorFilter to Modify a Drawable's Hue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4354939/understanding-the-use-of-colormatrix-and-colormatrixcolorfilter-to-modify-a-draw)

I assumed the asker was simply making a hue adjustment to a grayscale image, as he had originally asked. Now I know he must be making the hue adjustment to some **previously colored** image.

Ah well. The best form of learning comes from being forced to actually think about what you're trying to do!