# ImageView ColorFilter on non tranparent pixels. Clip

Tags: android, image, mask, clip

I have an ImageView with bitmap in it. This bitmap has alpha channel and transparent pixels.
When i try to use ColorFiter with Mode.OVERLAY (since honeycomb) - provided color overlay the whole imageview (whole rect), but i want only to overlay non transparent pixels. How can i clip the imageview's canvas to perform filter where i want ?

**UPDATED**

I have grey image in png:

[image]

When i try to use MODE_ATOP i get:

[image]

When i use OVERLAY i get:

[image]

And what i want to get:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's probably a more efficient way to do this (maybe by creating a [`ColorMatrixColorFilter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ColorMatrixColorFilter.html) to approximate it), but since [`Mode.OVERLAY`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PorterDuff.Mode.html) appear to be [hard to simplify otherwise](https://github.com/android/platform_external_skia/blob/master/src/core/SkXfermode.cpp#L202), here's some sample code that should implement what you want:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        final ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
        setContentView(imageView);

        final Paint paint = new Paint();
        Canvas c;

        final Bitmap src = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                android.R.drawable.sym_def_app_icon);
        final int overlayColor = Color.RED;

        final Bitmap bm1 = Bitmap.createBitmap(src.getWidth(), src.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
        c = new Canvas(bm1);
        paint.setColorFilter(new PorterDuffColorFilter(overlayColor, PorterDuff.Mode.OVERLAY));
        c.drawBitmap(src, 0, 0, paint);

        final Bitmap bm2 = Bitmap.createBitmap(src.getWidth(), src.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
        c = new Canvas(bm2);
        paint.setColorFilter(new PorterDuffColorFilter(overlayColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP));
        c.drawBitmap(src, 0, 0, paint);

        paint.setColorFilter(null);
        paint.setXfermode(new AvoidXfermode(overlayColor, 0, Mode.TARGET));
        c.drawBitmap(bm1, 0, 0, paint);

        imageView.setImageBitmap(bm2);
    }

}
```

In short, we draw the source bitmap and color using the `OVERLAY` mode, and then using a secondary bitmap (composited using `SRC_ATOP` mode), we combine it using [`AvoidXfermode`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/AvoidXfermode.html) to not draw over the transparent pixels.

Original image:

[image: original image]

Result:

[image: result]

Comment: Thank you, i'll try it right now, If you now how to achieve this using color matrix can you give a link to tutorial/sample/docs about how to do this ?

Comment: I've tried you sample, but the result of it is not that expected, i've paste updated question with pictures

Comment: Hmm .. I seem to get the result that you want, let me upload the screenshots to my answer.

Comment: And here's a [post with good information on ColorMatrixColorFilter](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4354939/1023092).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Overlay mode and then clip out the area that used to be transparent with the same bitmap using DST_ATOP xFerMode. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PorterDuff.Mode

```
private fun applyFilterToImage() {

    val bitmapCopy = Bitmap.createBitmap(originalImage.width, originalImage.height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
    val canvas = Canvas(bitmapCopy)

    val rnd = java.util.Random()
    val randomColor = Color.rgb(rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256))

    val paint = Paint()
    val porterDuffMode = PorterDuff.Mode.OVERLAY
    paint.colorFilter = PorterDuffColorFilter(randomColor, porterDuffMode)

    val maskPaint = Paint()
    maskPaint. xfermode = PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_ATOP)

    canvas.drawBitmap(originalImage, 0f, 0f, paint)

    canvas.drawBitmap(originalImage, 0f, 0f, maskPaint) //clips out the background that used to be transparent.

    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmapCopy)
}
```

[MarkerColorChangeGIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LWPC.gif)

Answer (score 0):

my case, merging 2 bitmap layer:

```
    final Paint paint = new Paint();
    final Bitmap dst_bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(front_bmp.getWidth(), front_bmp.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(dst_bmp);
    paint.setColorFilter(new PorterDuffColorFilter(Color.BLUE, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP));
    canvas.drawBitmap(black_bmp, 0, 0, null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(front_bmp, 0, 0, paint);
```

https://www.programming-books.io/essential/android/porterduff-mode-88a01690089945b4b2c505d1873e87e1