# ANDROID: what is the equivalent blend modes (porter duff) for Color and Hue

Tags: android, graphics, android-canvas

I'm trying to create an effect that I saw in an IOS application where the they used a blend mode of color and one of hue, but I couldn't find those blend modes in the PorterDuff.modes enum.
Do you know if there are equivalent modes in android?
Thanks!

Comment: From @Eric's answer, I understand that there's no porter-duff mode that does that, however, I was hoping that perhaps there's a library of these effects anywhere? (i.e. a set of pre-made color matrices)

Answer (score 2):

It depends exactly what you're trying to do; depending on the color used, you could use `PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY` or `SRC_OVER`; hue is a little more complex.

If none of the modes suit your needs (because, no, there are no default color/hue PorterDuff modes), [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7917978/1438733) may tickle your fancy. It's basically adjusting the hue of a [`ColorMatrix`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ColorMatrix.html), which can then be applied to a `Drawable`. (That process is elaborated on in the preceding answer's OP.)