# Color correction on android

Tags: android, image-processing, colors, bitmap

i am new in android programming. Now i am doing a color correction program using java for android platform.

In the program, i should be able to select a point on the bitmap and tell the program that it is actually white color, and the program will re-adjust all the pixels of that bitmap so that all the colors of that bitmap will be correct.

Can anyone tell me how can i do this? I am already able to retrieve a point from a bitmap now and calculate its RGB, but i got no idea how i can carry on. Please show me some examples or articles that i can read up on.

Thank you so much for your precious time. Hope to hear from you soon!

---

Resulting photo :
http://www.flickr.com/photos/92325795@N02/8392038944/in/photostream

My photo is being updated and despite of the quality/noise/color, there are the weird colors here and there. Anyone have any idea what i should do to remove it? Or even better improve on the method i am using? Heres the code:

The input is the bitmap to edit, inColor is the color of the nose in the photo to be edited, reqcolor is the color of my nose in the sample/optimum photo.

```
    public Bitmap shiftRGB(Bitmap input, int inColor, int reqColor){

        int deltaR = Color.red(reqColor) - Color.red(inColor);
        int deltaG = Color.green(reqColor) - Color.green(inColor);
        int deltaB = Color.blue(reqColor) - Color.blue(inColor);

        //--how many pixels ? --
        int w = input.getWidth();
        int h = input.getHeight();


        //-- change em all! --
        for (int i = 0 ; i < w; i++){
            for (int  j = 0 ; j < h ; j++ ){
                int pixColor = input.getPixel(i,j);

                //-- colors now ? --
                int inR = Color.red(pixColor);
                int inG = Color.green(pixColor);
                int inB = Color.blue(pixColor);

                if(inR > 255){ inR = 255;}
                if(inG > 255){ inG = 255;}
                if(inB > 255){ inB = 255;}
                if(inR < 0){ inR = 0;}
                if(inG < 0){ inG = 0;}
                if(inB < 0){ inB = 0;}

                //-- colors then --
                input.setPixel(i,j,Color.argb(255,inR + deltaR,inG + deltaG,inB           + deltaB));
            }
        }

        return input;
 }
```

Thank you so much for help me! I cant express my gratitude further than saying another thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you after some kind of brightness correction? Meaning that you choose e.g a gray colored pixel and tell it should be white - in which case all the pixels should be brightened with certain constant value in order to make this selected pixel white?

Comment: Yea harism! I think I can do that too because I need to change those color in those underexposed pictures back to how it should look without losing much infomation

Answer (score 1):

Read about some  [white-balancing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_balance) algorithms. See if you can implement some. Also note that android does not provides awt.graphics / BufferedImage API, used in majority of java tutorials out there.

Android provides [`ColorMatrixColorFilter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ColorMatrixColorFilter.html), for such use, [discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4354939/1531054).

A basic crude way to manipulate pixels:

```
public Bitmap shiftRGB(Bitmap input, int inColor, int reqColor){

    //--how much change ? --
    int deltaR = Color.red(reqColor) - Color.red(inColor);
    int deltaG = Color.green(reqColor) - Color.green(inColor);
    int deltaB = Color.blue(reqColor) - Color.blue(inColor);

    //--how many pixels ? --
    int w = input.getWidth();
    int h = input.getHeight();

    //-- change em all! --
    for (int i = 0 ; i < w; i++){
        for (int  j = 0 ; j < h ; j++ ){
            int pixColor = input.getPixel(i,j);

            //-- colors now ? --
            int inR = Color.red(pixColor);
            int inG = Color.green(pixColor);
            int inB = Color.blue(pixColor);

            //-- colors then --
            input.setPixel(i,j,Color.argb(255,inR + deltaR,inG + deltaG,inB + deltaB));

        }
    }

    //-- all done--
    return input;
}
```

Comment: I think this could work, but does anyone know how i can manipulate the  RGB of my image? Eg. multiplying a matrix over the entire picture. Not sure if my bitmap is in RGB565 format matters too.

Really thank you to those that help me out! :)

Comment: @user1950532 Updated answer, hope that'll get you started.

Comment: Thank you so much! seems like a great start for me. Will try it out and come back to update with my results. Thanks again :)

Comment: I have tried out the method you gave but added a little to it more to it and post my code and problem below :(