# Shading a bitmap another color

Tags: java, android

I want to shade a bitmap from one color to the other gradually (So as if it's going to glow from not so red to gradually getting redder.

I'm doing this per pixel but it's causing the app to jump, can someone show me a more efficient method?

```
private void adjustCountryBitmapColor()
{
    //TODO Possible memory leak in this method.
    mAllPixels = new int [ mCountryBitmap.getHeight()* mCountryBitmap.getWidth()];
    mCountryBitmap.getPixels(mAllPixels, 0, mCountryBitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0, mCountryBitmap.getWidth(),mCountryBitmap.getHeight());


    /*
    int alpha=argb>>24;
    int red=(argb & 0x00FF0000)>>16;
    int green=(argb & 0x0000FF00)>>8;
    int blue=(argb & 0x000000FF);
    */

    for(int i =0; i< mCountryBitmap.getHeight()*mCountryBitmap.getWidth(); i++)
    {
        if(mAllPixels[i]>>24 == -1)
        {
            /*AllPixels[i] == Color.BLACK)
            {
                mAllPixels[i] = Color.RED;
            }
            */


            mAllPixels[i] = Color.RED;


        }
    }

    System.out.println(mDeltaOffSet);

    //int alpha = mAllPixels[0]>>24;

    //System.out.println(alpha);

    mCountryBitmap.setPixels(mAllPixels, 0, mCountryBitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0, mCountryBitmap.getWidth(), mCountryBitmap.getHeight());
}
```

Comment: Doesn't have anything about shading bitmaps.

Comment: I hope this will help you..

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4354939/understanding-the-use-of-colormatrix-and-colormatrixcolorfilter-to-modify-a-draw

Answer (score 0):

Don't create an intermediate bitmap, that's going to take too long; there's `Canvas#drawBitmap(int[],....)` for exactly that reason. Also, have look whether `Paint#setColorFilter()` with a `ColorMatrixFilter` and a `ColorMatrix` can cover your color transforms.

Comment: ColorMatrixFilter doesn't let me shade the bitmap though, only replaces colors.

Answer (score 0):

I had found a good Image Processing library which is using GPU. Its is so fast that you can do live camera as well immediate image processing.

Library is provided by **[javierpuntonet / android-gpuimage](https://github.com/javierpuntonet/android-gpuimage)**. Just take a look at it and I am sure, you will get benefit of using it.

Comment: I can't be recreating the bitmap each time because it's ran 24 times every 30th of a second :P