# How can i set bitmap's specifies color area to transparent?

Tags: android, bitmap

There is a Bitmap with certain height and width,is there any way to set all WHITE color area in this bitmap to transparent?

Comment: i would suggest u to apply transparency via online editor

Comment: may be you are looking for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4354939/understanding-the-use-of-colormatrix-and-colormatrixcolorfilter-to-modify-a-draw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is actually a very simple way:
Just loop through your bitmap and check to see if a pixel is white and if it is clear it to an alpha transparent color, Here is the code:

```
class DrawingView extends View {
     Bitmap myBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(100, 100, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);

     @Override
     public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            myBitmap = findAllWhiteAndClear(myBitmap);
            canvas.drawBitmap(myBitmap, 0, 0, null); // draw result
     }

     private Bitmap findAllWhiteAndClear(Bitmap someBitmap) {
         int color = Color.WHITE;
         int width = someBitmap.getWidth()-1;
         int height = someBitmap.getHeight()-1;
         // loop going from up to down and on to the next column and repeat...
         for(int w = 0; i < width; ++w) {
             for(int j = 0; j < height; ++j) {
                 if(someBitmap.getPixel(w, j) == color) {
                     someBitmap.setPixel(w, j, Color.TRANSPARENT); // set any white pixels to a color to transparent
                 }
             }
         }
         return someBitmap;
    }
}
```

So over here I initialize some bitmap with a configuration such that it can store transparent pixels otherwise if the Bitmap.Config was Bitmap.Config.RBG_565 you would get an error or just a different color when trying to call setPixels() method on the bitmap. Then I just loop over it using a nested loop because I have two dimensions, and that's it!