# Set specific colour for grey scale image

Tags: java, android, colors, color-picker, colormatrix

In my app I have a Color-Picker matrix with a set of colors:

[image]

and some grey scale image - to say natural dress with pleats and different hue of grey:

[image]

Colors are in RGB format like to say "83334C". And I've managed to change the colour of the dress by converting the integer RGB to color-matrix filter like:

```
int red = (color & 0xFF0000) / 0xFFFF;
int green = (color & 0xFF00) / 0xFF;
int blue = color & 0xFF;
float[] colorTransform =
{       
0,0,0,0, red,  // R color
0,0,0,0, green,  // G color
0,0,0,0, blue,  // B color
0,0,0,1, 0
};
ColorMatrix colorMatrix = new ColorMatrix();
colorMatrix.set(colorTransform);
ColorMatrixColorFilter colorFilter = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(colorTransform); 
BitmapDrawable bd = DollFragment.this.drawableArray[1];
bd.setColorFilter(colorFilter);
```

But result I'm having is not what i wanted - all pleates and shades have disappeared:

[image]

The result I wanted to see shuld be something like:

[image]

Solution like below seems not to be correct because I'm changing the image which already have some RGB values set and the matrix below just applies some filter to the image instead of setting the necessary color:

```
float[] colorTransform =
{       
red/255, 0    , 0    , 0, 0,  // R color
0    , green/255, 0    , 0, 0,  // G color
0    , 0    , blue/255, 0, 0,  // B color
0    , 0    , 0    , 1, 0
};
```

I've checked [very useful link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4354939/understanding-the-use-of-colormatrix-and-colormatrixcolorfilter-to-modify-a-draw) and some others, but didn't find the answer to my question. I'm sure that I have to use some mathematic formulas but have no idea which.

The question is how to change the color of the grey image to a specific color and not to lose the existing shades?

Thanks a lot for your suggestions!

Comment: Hey did you find the answer to your question?