# Unfortunately App has stopped (Android Studio)

Tags: android, xml

I dont know why this message is coming ... the app is opening fine but as soon as I change the seekbars in the app the message pops up and app stops.

I am using a blank activity and m posting the *.xml* and *.java* files.Please reply.

**linearlayout.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
         <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:orientation="vertical"
             android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
             android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
             android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
             android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
             tools:context=".MainActivity" >

             <TextView
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:text="R" />

             <SeekBar
                 android:id="@+id/sb_red"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:max="255"
                 android:progress="128" />

             <TextView
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:text="G" />

             <SeekBar
                 android:id="@+id/sb_green"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:max="255"
                 android:progress="128" />

             <TextView
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:text="B" />

             <SeekBar
                 android:id="@+id/sb_blue"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:max="255"
                 android:progress="128" />



             <ImageView
                 android:id="@+id/iv_show"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:src="@drawable/game" />

         </LinearLayout>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.rohit2906.rgbvalues" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.rohit2906.rgbvalues;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.ColorMatrix;
import android.graphics.ColorMatrixColorFilter;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.Paint;



public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private SeekBar sb_red, sb_green, sb_blue;
    private ImageView iv_show;
    private Bitmap afterBitmap;
    private Paint paint;
    private Canvas canvas;
    private Bitmap baseBitmap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.linearlayout);

        iv_show = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_show);
        sb_red = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.sb_red);
        sb_green = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.sb_green);
        sb_blue = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.sb_blue);


        sb_red.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(seekBarChange);
        sb_green.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(seekBarChange);
        sb_blue.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(seekBarChange);
        // Get a picture from a resource file
        baseBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
         R.drawable.game);
        // Empty picture gets a and baseBitmap the same size editable
        afterBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(baseBitmap.getWidth(),
        baseBitmap.getHeight(), baseBitmap.getConfig());
        canvas = new Canvas(afterBitmap);
        paint = new Paint();
    }
    private SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener seekBarChange = new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

                 @Override
                 public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                     // Gets the current value of each SeekBar
                     float progressR = sb_red.getProgress()/128f;
                     float progressG = sb_green.getProgress()/128f;
                     float progressB = sb_blue.getProgress()/128f;

                     Log.i("main", "R: G: B="+progressR+": "+progressG+": "+progressB);
                     // According to the definition of the RGB matrix SeekBar
                     float[] src = new float[]{
                             progressR, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                             0, progressG, 0, 0, 0,
                             0, 0, progressB, 0, 0,
                           };
                     // The definition of ColorMatrix, and specify the RGB matrix
                     ColorMatrix colorMatrix = new ColorMatrix();
                     colorMatrix.set(src);
                     // Set the Paint color
                     paint.setColorFilter(new ColorMatrixColorFilter(src));
                    // By specifying the RGB matrix Paint of the original picture of the blank picture
                    canvas.drawBitmap(baseBitmap, new Matrix(), paint);
                    iv_show.setImageBitmap(afterBitmap);
               }

                 @Override
                 public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                }
                        @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                         boolean fromUser) {
                }
             };


}
```

logcat

```
02-22 15:45:37.334    1768-1768/com.example.rohit2906.rgbvalues I/art﹕ Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
02-22 15:45:38.684    1768-1780/com.example.rohit2906.rgbvalues I/art﹕ Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 7(272B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 26MB/26MB, paused 33.108ms total 56.416ms
02-22 15:45:38.804    1768-1804/com.example.rohit2906.rgbvalues D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Render dirty regions requested: true
02-22 15:45:38.806    1768-1768/com.example.rohit2906.rgbvalues D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xae0d2dc0, tid 1768
02-22 15:45:38.810    1768-1768/com.example.rohit2906.rgbvalues D/Atlas﹕ Validating map...
02-22 15:45:38.970    1768-1804/com.example.rohit2906.rgbvalues D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xae0d2f00, tid 1804
02-22 15:45:38.972    1768-1804/com.example.rohit2906.rgbvalues I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
02-22 15:45:39.117    1768-1804/com.example.rohit2906.rgbvalues D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
02-22 15:45:39.245    1768-1804/com.example.rohit2906.rgbvalues W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
02-22 15:45:39.245    1768-1804/com.example.rohit2906.rgbvalues W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa6c8d660, error=EGL_SUCCESS
02-22 15:45:41.195    1768-1768/com.example.rohit2906.rgbvalues I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 108 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-22 15:46:16.236    1768-1768/com.example.rohit2906.rgbvalues I/art﹕ Alloc sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 0(0B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 3% free, 53MB/55MB, paused 1.103ms total 18.769ms
02-22 15:46:16.252    1768-1768/com.example.rohit2906.rgbvalues I/art﹕ Alloc partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 201(9KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 6% free, 53MB/57MB, paused 1.110ms total 16.307ms
02-22 15:46:16.272    1768-1768/com.example.rohit2906.rgbvalues I/art﹕ Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 8(12KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 6% free, 53MB/57MB, paused 11.662ms total 18.752ms
02-22 15:46:16.272    1768-1768/com.example.rohit2906.rgbvalues I/art﹕ Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 13MB allocation
02-22 15:46:16.344    1768-1768/com.example.rohit2906.rgbvalues I/art﹕ Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 11(344B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 6% free, 53MB/57MB, paused 879us total 71.595ms
02-22 15:46:16.344    1768-1768/com.example.rohit2906.rgbvalues E/art﹕ Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 13824012 byte allocation with 4194304 free bytes and 10MB until OOM"
02-22 15:46:16.344    1768-1768/com.example.rohit2906.rgbvalues D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
    --------- beginning of crash
02-22 15:46:16.345    1768-1768/com.example.rohit2906.rgbvalues E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.rohit2906.rgbvalues, PID: 1768
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 13824012 byte allocation with 4194304 free bytes and 10MB until OOM
            at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
            at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
            at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:817)
            at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:794)
            at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:761)
            at com.example.rohit2906.rgbvalues.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:46)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3912)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1284)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Comment: post your logcat output

Comment: LogCat message please.

Comment: I am getting yellow line maybe warnings that says hardcoded should use @string ... in textview . what does this mean?

Comment: Hi lets try my solution I think this resolve your issue

Comment: and one more think you use to big image and you have OutOfMemory Error

Comment: no i am using the right image as I have tried different images for the same .Thanks Konrad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot about alpha line in `src` array.

Replace:

```
  float[] src = new float[]{
         progressR, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, progressG, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0, progressB, 0, 0,
  };
```

with this:

```
  float[] src = new float[]{
         progressR, 0, 0, 0, 0, //Red
         0, progressG, 0, 0, 0, //Green
         0, 0, progressB, 0, 0, //Blue
         0, 0, 0, 1, 0, //alpha
  };
```

When you  call `set(float[])` method on `ColorMatrix` object,  as is shown in the code below:

```
 ColorMatrix colorMatrix = new ColorMatrix();
 colorMatrix.set(src);
```

you get exception and you application is crashed. The `src` array has to be the same length as array in `ColorMartix` object. It has to have 20 length.

Comment: thnks it solved my problem. I dont have much reputation will promote your answer as soon as I can.

Comment: Can you briefly please explain me what exactly the code is doing . It is changing the rgb values but please tell me what is the algorithm it is using.

Comment: And here is info about ColorMatrix http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4354939/understanding-the-use-of-colormatrix-and-colormatrixcolorfilter-to-modify-a-draw

Comment: Basically the method set(float[]) copy your array to array from ColorMatrix object by method  System.arraycopy(src, 0, mArray, 0, 20); and this method has condition which checks that the arrays - destination and source arrays - have the same length - if not throws exception

Comment: Thankyou very much Konrad. Actually I am doing a project on android using for image Processing. Can you give me your email id I want to ask and discuss more things.

Comment: I think that the stackoverflow is the best place to discuss and asking. Here is many people better than me, and you can be sure that someone always help you :) Good luck.