# Faster alternative for getPixel and getPixel in Android Bitmap?

Tags: android, performance, android-ndk, android-bitmap, renderscript

I'm using the methods `getPixel` and `setPixel` for my `Bitmap` and it's so slow (`getPixels` too). I want to process every pixel of the `Bitmap` and then create another `Bitmap`. How can I get access to pixels by RenderScript or using C++? I think they are faster but I don't know how to do .

This is what I do using `getPixel` / `setPixel`:

```
  bitmap.getPixels(colorArray, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);

    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            int g = Color.green(colorArray[y * width + x]);
            int b = Color.blue(colorArray[y * width + x]);
            int r = Color.red(colorArray[y * width + x]);
            //some color changes ....
            colorArray[y * width + x] = Color.rgb(r, g, b);
            returnBitmap.setPixel(x, y, colorArray[y * width + x]);
        }
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: what kind of process are you doing ? are you rotating, scaling, changing colors ? does the process need to be applied in a pixel-by-pixel approach ?

Comment: I've updated the question, I want to change colors

Comment: For your color changes, you'd better use a **ColorMatrix**, instead of a pixel-by-pixel double loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `getPixels()` to get all the pixels, modify the values in the `byte[]`, then call `setPixels()` to store all the pixels at once.  The overhead of calling `setPixel()` on each individual pixel is killing your performance.

If it's still not fast enough, you can pass the array to an NDK function.

If you're doing live processing of Camera images, you can get [even fancier](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kH9kCP2T5Gg).

Comment: A ColorMatrix is much faster than a per pixel (double) loop.

Comment: @DerGolem If you have time to put together sample code, you should write that up as an answer -- I think that's the correct approach.

Comment: Sorry, not these days (I'm going to finish a work in a hurry). I think left the OP with something to investigate on: a keyword they can search and discover how many things a ColorMatrix can allow (sepia toning, greyscaling, color toning, negative, ...). And at warp speed!

Comment: @fadden thank you for the answer. I'm trying the function setPixels but I don't know if it is enough.. How can I use the NDK function? (something of code) DerGolem I already use ColorMatrix for saturation, luminosity etc. but in this case I just need to bring R G B from 3 different bitmaps and put into a new Bitmap (as Harris effect) efficiently

Comment: @FabrizioBilleci Start here: https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html .  Pass your arrays into a native function and just do like you do now, but in C++ rather than Java. Using the NDK and JNI for the first time has a steep learning curve, so it's generally wise to exhaust other approaches first.

Comment: You possibly want to get the modifications from 3 different images and then overlay the variations to compose a new one?

Comment: Thank you fadden, I'll try. @DerGolem, exactly I take R from the first bitmap, G from the second and B from the third bitmap and then put RGB in a new bitmap. I use this method to create Harris picture and even 3D anaglyph pictures (using the same bitmap translated for GB matrix.) and I wait 5-20 seconds before it's complete, too much time even if I reduce the height to 2000px and the width proportionally

Comment: Very easy, I'd say... Greyscale a picture, tone it in blue (2 ColorMatrices combined). Same with another one, tone it in red. Same with another one, tone it in green.. Then overlay the 3 pictures. Done. The overall processing should be really fast.

Comment: Hi @DerGolem, now I'm able to take RGB from a bitmap using ColorMatrix..but how to overlay the 3 images? In this process I need to put the RGB matrix in every pixels and show the color diffences in the pixels where R G B don't compose the same thing. I don't know if it's clean enough to understand.. You can see searching "Harris effect", ColorMatrix is really fast, thank you! Now I need how to add the different channels.

Comment: You can combine 2 images: http://www.jondev.net/articles/Combining_2_Images_in_Android_using_Canvas **Repeat twice**

Comment: to modify the original image based on the color in the pixels array (much faster than using getPixel): if (pixels[y*width+x] == ... ) bmp.setPixel(x, y, Color.BLACK);

Answer (score 1):

I found this ColorMatrix example

```
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2007 The Android Open Source Project
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package com.example.android.apis.graphics;

import com.example.android.apis.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.*;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;

public class ColorMatrixSample extends GraphicsActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new SampleView(this));
    }

    private static class SampleView extends View {
        private Paint mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        private ColorMatrix mCM = new ColorMatrix();
        private Bitmap mBitmap;
        private float mSaturation;
        private float mAngle;

        public SampleView(Context context) {
            super(context);

            mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                                                   R.drawable.balloons);
        }

        private static void setTranslate(ColorMatrix cm, float dr, float dg,
                                         float db, float da) {
            cm.set(new float[] {
                   2, 0, 0, 0, dr,
                   0, 2, 0, 0, dg,
                   0, 0, 2, 0, db,
                   0, 0, 0, 1, da });
        }

        private static void setContrast(ColorMatrix cm, float contrast) {
            float scale = contrast + 1.f;
               float translate = (-.5f * scale + .5f) * 255.f;
            cm.set(new float[] {
                   scale, 0, 0, 0, translate,
                   0, scale, 0, 0, translate,
                   0, 0, scale, 0, translate,
                   0, 0, 0, 1, 0 });
        }

        private static void setContrastTranslateOnly(ColorMatrix cm, float contrast) {
            float scale = contrast + 1.f;
               float translate = (-.5f * scale + .5f) * 255.f;
            cm.set(new float[] {
                   1, 0, 0, 0, translate,
                   0, 1, 0, 0, translate,
                   0, 0, 1, 0, translate,
                   0, 0, 0, 1, 0 });
        }

        private static void setContrastScaleOnly(ColorMatrix cm, float contrast) {
            float scale = contrast + 1.f;
               float translate = (-.5f * scale + .5f) * 255.f;
            cm.set(new float[] {
                   scale, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                   0, scale, 0, 0, 0,
                   0, 0, scale, 0, 0,
                   0, 0, 0, 1, 0 });
        }

        @Override protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            Paint paint = mPaint;
            float x = 20;
            float y = 20;

            canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);

            paint.setColorFilter(null);
            canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, x, y, paint);

            ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix();

            mAngle += 2;
            if (mAngle > 180) {
                mAngle = 0;
            }

            //convert our animated angle [-180...180] to a contrast value of [-1..1]
            float contrast = mAngle / 180.f;

            setContrast(cm, contrast);
            paint.setColorFilter(new ColorMatrixColorFilter(cm));
            canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, x + mBitmap.getWidth() + 10, y, paint);

            setContrastScaleOnly(cm, contrast);
            paint.setColorFilter(new ColorMatrixColorFilter(cm));
            canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, x, y + mBitmap.getHeight() + 10, paint);

            setContrastTranslateOnly(cm, contrast);
            paint.setColorFilter(new ColorMatrixColorFilter(cm));
            canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, x, y + 2*(mBitmap.getHeight() + 10),
                              paint);

            invalidate();
        }
    }
}
```

Taken from http://alvinalexander.com/java/jwarehouse/android-examples/platforms/android-6/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/ColorMatrixSample.java.shtml

Also somebody else has a very good answer right here in SO
[Understanding the Use of ColorMatrix and ColorMatrixColorFilter to Modify a Drawable's Hue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4354939/understanding-the-use-of-colormatrix-and-colormatrixcolorfilter-to-modify-a-draw)