# Change color of drawable (.png) in code, result still has a tint to it

Tags: android, colors, drawable

I am trying to change the color of a drawable png in code. I have tried many different ways but so far I can only change the color it's tint. The png is grey, I want it to be completely white.

I have tried many different ways to accomplish this.
I tried to set a [colorFilter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5837189/3972558) which almost worked but left a tint. 
I also tried a [colorMatrix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11171509/3972558) but here I was left with the same tint too.
Implemented a [whole class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4354939/understanding-the-use-of-colormatrix-and-colormatrixcolorfilter-to-modify-a-draw) but could not get it to work because it used relative changes instead of absolute.

I think the reason may be that the whole png is transparent, but I am not sure. Any suggestions?