# Apply ColorFilter but preserve transparent shadow in PNG file

Tags: android, drawable, colorfilter

I am applying a ColorFilter to a `Drawable` I wanted to know if's possible to change the color of a drawable but preserve the shadow in it.

Something like this:

[image]

Where if you applied something like:

```
view.getBackground().setColorFilter(new PorterDuffColorFilter(itemView.getResources().getColor(R.color.green_500), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```

It would apply that `ColorFilter` but preserve the shadow and alpha values.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: use `PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR`

Comment: Makes my drawable completely transparent

Comment: https://softwyer.wordpress.com/2012/01/21/1009/

Comment: @AndyRoid Which view are you trying to apply the `ColorFilter` to? Are you using the `FloatingActionButton` from the Android Support Library or any similiar library?

Answer (score 3):

I think that you need a hue shifter. If so, using the `ColorFilterGenerator` proposed in [Understanding the Use of ColorMatrix and ColorMatrixColorFilter to Modify a Drawable's Hue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4354939/understanding-the-use-of-colormatrix-and-colormatrixcolorfilter-to-modify-a-draw/7917978#7917978) you just need to do:

```
view.getBackground().setColorFilter(ColorFilterGenerator.adjustHue(180));
```

The result looks like this (hue rotated 180 degrees):

[image]

**Note:** All credit for this answer must go to @Richard Lalancette for his awesome answer to the question I linked

**Update from the comments:**

As you need to specify the target color, you can calculate the source and target HSV values and use the `ColorFilterGenerator` to shift the hue. For example:

```
// Your source color (The RGB color from your original image is 255,85,78)
float[] hsvSource = new float[3];
Color.RGBToHSV(255, 85, 78, hsvSource);

// The color whose hue you want to achieve (green for example)
float[] hsvTarget = new float[3];
Color.RGBToHSV(0, 200, 18, hsvTarget);

view.getBackground().setColorFilter(ColorFilterGenerator.adjustHue(hsvTarget[0] - hsvSource[0]));
```

Note that this approach only takes into account the hue values of the colors to shift it.

**Update from the comments:**

@Jared Rummler's wonderful answer ([Understanding the Use of ColorMatrix and ColorMatrixColorFilter to Modify a Drawable's Hue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4354939/understanding-the-use-of-colormatrix-and-colormatrixcolorfilter-to-modify-a-draw/32703759#32703759)) takes your drawable as a parameter so you don't need to specify the source color:

```
view.getBackground().setColorFilter(ColorFilterGenerator.from(view.getBackground()).to(Color.GREEN));
```

Comment: I've been using that before but can't seem to set a specific color

Comment: @Jared Rummler's answer is brilliant. I'm upvoting it

Comment: Will test out both, I've tested Jared's answer before a few months ago but maybe I was doing something wrong thanks for the updates guys! Both are brilliant answers

Comment: To be clear I know that shifting hues is done by rotating the angle of the hue, but in my case I need to set a specific color altogether and preserve shadows and transparency.

Comment: As I have stated in the last update, @Jared 's solution takes your existing drawable as a parameter, gets it's average color and transforms it to your target color. And not only his method preserves shadows and transparency, but also takes into account the saturation and brightness (besides the hue), that's the main reason because it's so amazing

Comment: I was able to get the solution to work but the colors were off. I think it's workable with some more fixing of Jarred's solution. It's a simple RGB(255, 0, 0) to an adjusted color value and I was still get off colors. I'll investigate why this is happening.

Answer (score 1):

The right (and probably only) way to achieve what you want is to split the drawable into multiple layers and use a layerDrawable to compose them.
At that point you can have the color layer that you can change (and you wouldn't even need to use porter duff)

Answer (score 0):

i was facing issue with transparent part of png and dropshadow, this code worked for me.

```
  // The colorPrimary is color you want to achieve 
    float colorRed = Color.red(colorPrimary) / 255f;
    float colorGreen = Color.green(colorPrimary) / 255f;
    float colorBlue = Color.blue(colorPrimary) / 255f;

    drawable.setColorFilter(new ColorMatrixColorFilter(new ColorMatrix(new float[]{
            1 - colorRed, 0,              0,             0,     colorRed * 255,
            0,            1 - colorGreen, 0,             0,     colorGreen * 255,
            0,            0,              1 - colorBlue, 0,     colorBlue * 255,
            0,            0,              0,             Color.alpha(colorPrimary) / 255f, 0,
    })));
    img.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```