# Animate images with flickr effect Android

Tags: android, animation

I want to show images in Android with flickr effect, like a semaphore.

Do you know how can i do this? I supose that some animation and show with alpha channel, any example?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> like a semaphore

I'm not sure that I got the point. If you want to change the color you can play with [ColorMatrix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7917978/1348726):

```
image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ValueAnimator animation = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0f, 1f);
        animation.setDuration(2000);
        animation.setRepeatCount(1);
        animation.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.REVERSE);
        animation.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                image.setColorFilter(ColorFilterGenerator.adjustHue(animation.getAnimatedFraction() * 180f));
            }
        });
        animation.start();
    }
});
```

[image]

If you want to make the image blink you can just change the visibility:

```
image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ValueAnimator animation = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0f, 1f);
        animation.setDuration(750);
        animation.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
        animation.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                image.setVisibility(animation.getAnimatedFraction() > 0.5 ? View.INVISIBLE : View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
        animation.start();
    }
});
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!! Good solution