# Change the color balance of a Drawable

Tags: android, drawable

It is possible to change the color balance of a Drawable ?

For example, I would like to convert
[image] to =>   [image]

I try this but it change all the colors of my Drawable to one unique color  :

```
        Drawable drawable; // my drawable
        float r = Color.red(110) / 255f;
        float g = Color.green(150) / 255f;
        float b = Color.blue(200) / 255f;

        ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix(new float[] {
                // Change red channel
                r, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                // Change green channel
                0, g, 0, 0, 0,
                // Change blue channel
                0, 0, b, 0, 0,
                // Keep alpha channel
                0, 0, 0, 1, 0,
        });
        ColorMatrixColorFilter cf = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(cm);

        drawable.setColorFilter(cf);
```

I specify **I don't want** to split my src image into 2 or more layers and colorify one of them.

Comment: you need to split your src image into 2 or more layers and colorify one of them

Comment: it's the only way ? :(

Comment: well i think there are some algorithms for that but i dont think they are simple and short...

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32703759/1048340

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply a tint with the desired color to your image using `mutate().setColorFilter()`, and set the Drawable with the new color into your ImageView:

```
   ImageView imgImagen = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.myImageView);
    Drawable myImage = getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.boy );
    //Using red color.
    myImage.mutate().setColorFilter(0xffff0000, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
   imgImagen.setImageDrawable(myImage);
```

For example using this `ImageView`,

```
   <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/myImageView"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:src="@drawable/boy"
        android:contentDescription="" />
```

you will have this image as result:

[image]

You can use too the color defined in your example:

```
 myImage.mutate().setColorFilter(Color.argb(255, 110, 150, 200), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see that your character have eyes and some attribute which need to be safe during color change, so we need more control on that resource therefore we will convert it to bitmap:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.brown_man);
```

Your bitmap might be not mutable so in order to make it mutable:

```
Bitmap myBitmap = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565, true);
```

Then we have to [`getPixels()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#getPixels(int[],%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) And re [`setPixels()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#setPixels(int[],%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) with specified color:

```
int[] pixels = new int[myBitmap.getHeight() * myBitmap.getWidth()];
    myBitmap.getPixels(pixels, 0, myBitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0, myBitmap.getWidth(), myBitmap.getHeight());

    for (int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++) {

        if (pixels[i] == color /*Color to change int value*/)
            pixels[i] = newColor /*The new color you want to change*/;
    }
    myBitmap.setPixels(pixels, 0, myBitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0, myBitmap.getWidth(), myBitmap.getHeight());
```

Thus, you can use this bitmap as you wish.

**Some things to take considering:**

- Your resource character must have a height resolution color to make it easy to specify and change.