# Dynamically colorizing drawable in android studio (kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to dynamically colorize an image of a meadow after the time of day (hour). Basically, I want to check for time of day, and change the hue/brightness of the meadow to a custom (pre-set) setting. For example, at midday it is the standard green image, at nighttime I wish to give it a blue hue and darken it. Similar for other times of day.

[image: standard green image]

I am completely new to android studio and kotlin, and I can't quite figure out how to do this. Hope someone is able to help me.

Comment: What have you tried so far. Show some codes.

Answer (score 0):

you might want to give this a shot .  for your case

just copy this class `ColorFilterGenerator` to your project .

```
    public class ColorFilterGenerator
{
    /**
 * Creates a HUE ajustment ColorFilter
 * @see http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/9e215c83c3819953
 * @see http://gskinner.com/blog/archives/2007/12/colormatrix_cla.html
 * @param value degrees to shift the hue.
 * @return
 */
public static ColorFilter adjustHue( float value )
{
    ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix();

    adjustHue(cm, value);

    return new ColorMatrixColorFilter(cm);
}

/**
 * @see http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/9e215c83c3819953
 * @see http://gskinner.com/blog/archives/2007/12/colormatrix_cla.html
 * @param cm
 * @param value
 */
public static void adjustHue(ColorMatrix cm, float value)
{
    value = cleanValue(value, 180f) / 180f * (float) Math.PI;
    if (value == 0)
    {
        return;
    }
    float cosVal = (float) Math.cos(value);
    float sinVal = (float) Math.sin(value);
    float lumR = 0.213f;
    float lumG = 0.715f;
    float lumB = 0.072f;
    float[] mat = new float[]
    { 
            lumR + cosVal * (1 - lumR) + sinVal * (-lumR), lumG + cosVal * (-lumG) + sinVal * (-lumG), lumB + cosVal * (-lumB) + sinVal * (1 - lumB), 0, 0, 
            lumR + cosVal * (-lumR) + sinVal * (0.143f), lumG + cosVal * (1 - lumG) + sinVal * (0.140f), lumB + cosVal * (-lumB) + sinVal * (-0.283f), 0, 0,
            lumR + cosVal * (-lumR) + sinVal * (-(1 - lumR)), lumG + cosVal * (-lumG) + sinVal * (lumG), lumB + cosVal * (1 - lumB) + sinVal * (lumB), 0, 0, 
            0f, 0f, 0f, 1f, 0f, 
            0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1f };
    cm.postConcat(new ColorMatrix(mat));
}

protected static float cleanValue(float p_val, float p_limit)
{
    return Math.min(p_limit, Math.max(-p_limit, p_val));
}
}
```

Now for your use case scenario.

```
ImageView meadow = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.meadow );

    if (its day ){
    meadow.setColorFilter(ColorFilterGenerator.adjustHue(100));
    }else if(its night){
    meadow.setColorFilter(ColorFilterGenerator.adjustHue(162));
    }
```

PS: you need to adjust hue value according to your need . i've just represented an example.

`ColorFilterGenreator` credit goes to [@Richard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7917978/6880611)

Comment: Thank you so much, I will give this a try