# How to adjust Hue Saturation and Brightness of an image or widget in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, image-processing, colormatrix

In my Flutter app, I have an image and three sliders, one for **Hue**, one for **Saturation**, and one for **Brightness**, and I'm trying to figure out how to use the `ColorFiltered` widget to make these adjustments, but I can't figure out what to put in for the `ColorFilter.matrix`.

My code looks something like this:

```
ColorFiltered(
  colorFilter: ColorFilter.matrix(
    // What goes here?
  ),
  child: Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      image: DecorationImage(
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
        image: NetworkImage(myImageUrl),
      )
    )
  )
)
```

Does anyone know how to generate a color filter matrix based on HSV values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added **BananaNeil's answer** into the [Themed package](https://pub.dev/packages/themed).

Use the provided `ChangeColors` widget to change the brightness, saturation and hue of any widget, including images, like this:

```
ChangeColors(
   hue: 0.55,
   brightness: 0.2,
   saturation: 0.1,
   child: Image.asset('myImage.png'),
);
```

Parameters are:

## brightness

- Negative value will make it darker (`-1` is darkest).
- Positive value will make it lighter (`1` is the maximum, but you can go above it).
- `0.0` is unchanged.

## saturation

- Negative value will make it less saturated (`-1` is greyscale).
- Positive value will make it more saturated (`1` is the maximum, but you can go above it).
- `0.0` is unchanged.

## hue

- From `-1.0` to `1.0` (Note: `1.0` wraps into `-1.0`, such as `1.2` is the same as `-0.8`).
- `0.0` is unchanged. Adding or subtracting multiples of `2.0` also keeps it unchanged.

**Please note:** The difference from the `ChangeColors` widget to BananaNeil's answer is that the widget is a proper `StatelessWidget`, code is null-safe, it fixes the limits of saturation so that you don't get weird effects, and the documentation was added explaining the parameters. If you don't want to add a package, just copy the code from [GitHub](https://github.com/marcglasberg/themed/blob/main/lib/src/change_colors.dart).

Comment: SO COOL! Thank you so much! 

Comment: I did not double check this, but I'm going to mark it as the accepted answer because it seems to do what I did, but made the implementation much easier.

Answer (score 22):

To solve this issue, I built an `ImageFilter` widget, which can be used like this:

```dart
ImageFilter(
  hue: 0.1,
  brightness: -0.6,
  saturation: 0.8,
  child: Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      image: DecorationImage(
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
        image: NetworkImage(imageUrl),
      ),
    )
  )
)
```

It takes percentage inputs in decimal form between -1 and 1.

Which uses 3 layers of the ColorFiltered widget:

```dart
Widget ImageFilter({brightness, saturation, hue, child}) {
  return ColorFiltered(
    colorFilter: ColorFilter.matrix(
      ColorFilterGenerator.brightnessAdjustMatrix(
        value: brightness,
      )
    ),
    child: ColorFiltered(
      colorFilter: ColorFilter.matrix(
        ColorFilterGenerator.saturationAdjustMatrix(
          value: saturation,
        )
      ),
      child: ColorFiltered(
        colorFilter: ColorFilter.matrix(
          ColorFilterGenerator.hueAdjustMatrix(
            value: hue,
          )
        ),
        child: child,
      )
    )
  );
}
```

To generate the filter matrix, I used help from this answer to a similar question for android: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7917978/937841 and created a `ColorFilterGenerator` that works in flutter:

```dart
import 'dart:math';

class ColorFilterGenerator {
    static List<double> hueAdjustMatrix({double value}) {
      value = value * pi;

      if (value == 0)
        return [
          1,0,0,0,0,
          0,1,0,0,0,
          0,0,1,0,0,
          0,0,0,1,0,
        ];

      double cosVal = cos(value);
      double sinVal = sin(value);
      double lumR = 0.213;
      double lumG = 0.715;
      double lumB = 0.072;

      return List<double>.from(<double>[
        (lumR + (cosVal * (1 - lumR))) + (sinVal * (-lumR)), (lumG + (cosVal * (-lumG))) + (sinVal * (-lumG)), (lumB + (cosVal * (-lumB))) + (sinVal * (1 - lumB)), 0, 0, (lumR + (cosVal * (-lumR))) + (sinVal * 0.143), (lumG + (cosVal * (1 - lumG))) + (sinVal * 0.14), (lumB + (cosVal * (-lumB))) + (sinVal * (-0.283)), 0, 0, (lumR + (cosVal * (-lumR))) + (sinVal * (-(1 - lumR))), (lumG + (cosVal * (-lumG))) + (sinVal * lumG), (lumB + (cosVal * (1 - lumB))) + (sinVal * lumB), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0,
      ]).map((i) => i.toDouble()).toList();
    }

    static List<double> brightnessAdjustMatrix({double value}}) {
      if (value <= 0)
        value = value * 255;
      else value = value * 100

      if (value == 0)
        return [
          1,0,0,0,0,
          0,1,0,0,0,
          0,0,1,0,0,
          0,0,0,1,0,
        ];

      return List<double>.from(<double>[
        1, 0, 0, 0, value, 0, 1, 0, 0, value, 0, 0, 1, 0, value, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0
      ]).map((i) => i.toDouble()).toList();
    }

    static List<double> saturationAdjustMatrix({double value}) {
      value = value * 100;

      if (value == 0)
        return [
          1,0,0,0,0,
          0,1,0,0,0,
          0,0,1,0,0,
          0,0,0,1,0,
        ];

      double x = ((1 + ((value > 0) ? ((3 * value) / 100) : (value / 100)))).toDouble();
      double lumR = 0.3086;
      double lumG = 0.6094;
      double lumB = 0.082;

      return List<double>.from(<double>[
        (lumR * (1 - x)) + x, lumG * (1 - x), lumB * (1 - x),
        0, 0,
        lumR * (1 - x),
        (lumG * (1 - x)) + x,
        lumB * (1 - x),
        0, 0,
        lumR * (1 - x),
        lumG * (1 - x),
        (lumB * (1 - x)) + x,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0,
      ]).map((i) => i.toDouble()).toList();
    }
}
```

I would bet that there is a way to concatenate the hue/saturation/brightness matrices (like was done in the android question I mentioned above), and only use 1 color filtered matrix (which would likely be more efficient), but this worked for my case.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your work around, it is working good.
Is it possible to share contrast adjust too?
At the Android question I can see that someone explained HSBC adjustment and I hope you could help me complete the code for contrast part.
Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Prooshani - if you post a new stackoverflow question, and you tag me in a comment, I'll help you out!

Comment: Thank you @BananaNeil , I have already figured it out by myself.
I can share the result if needed.

Comment: Probably a good thing to do for the community! I'd recommend putting it into a new Q/A though.

Comment: @Prooshani how did you add contrast? can you share it?

Comment: @BananaNeil can you help me on how to add Contrast to an image? here's my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69544333/flutter-how-to-adjust-add-contrast-to-the-image

Comment: @AgentRed please find your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69575142/how-to-set-contrast-hue-and-brightness-of-an-image-in-flutter

Answer (score 1):

We have to include a color matrix in this.
Some examples are:

```
static const ColorFilter sepia = ColorFilter.matrix(<double>[
 0.393, 0.769, 0.189, 0, 0,
 0.349, 0.686, 0.168, 0, 0,
 0.272, 0.534, 0.131, 0, 0,
 0,     0,     0,     1, 0]);

static const ColorFilter greyscale = ColorFilter.matrix(<double>[
 0.2126, 0.7152, 0.0722, 0, 0,
 0.2126, 0.7152, 0.0722, 0, 0,
 0.2126, 0.7152, 0.0722, 0, 0,
 0,      0,      0,      1, 0]);
```

Just copy the matrix above to get a sepia or greyscale filter.

Answer (score 0):

I've further tweaked BananaNeil & Marcelo Glasberg answers, combining the 3 matrices into 1 while also adding support for adjusting a child's contrast, thereby improving performance.

```dart
ColorFiltered(
  colorFilter: ColorFilters.matrix(brightness: -0.5, saturation: 0.5),
  child: Image.network('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c6/500_x_500_SMPTE_Color_Bars.png'),
);
```

It is available as part of the [Stevia](https://github.com/forus-labs/cauldron/tree/master/stevia) package.

Alternatively, if you don't want to add the package, you can copy the [source code](https://github.com/forus-labs/cauldron/blob/c67d903d5de2109559126406b964b57322ee2f09/stevia/lib/src/services/color_filters.dart).