# Flutter - How to adjust/add contrast to the image?

Tags: flutter, dart

I've been trying this function:
https://pub.dev/documentation/image/latest/image/contrast.html

I don't think I'm using it correctly.

```
contrast(Image.network(snapshot.data.toString(),20), //something like this
```

I believe you need to convert your image to something like **Uint32List** first.

Is there any way to add contrast to a url image?