# How to get Bitmap from another Bitmap and color?

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

I am writing a game program for educational purposes. I'm using the **SurfaceView** class. The program displays the images on the screen using the **Canvas** object. The **drawable** folder contains a png-image. By the name of the picture **"bitmapName"** I get the **Bitmap** using this code

```
int resID = context.getResources().getIdentifier(bitmapName, "drawable", context.getPackageName());
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), resID);
```

I use the **drawBitmap()** method to draw the resulting **Bitmap** to the screen. The problem is that the object on which this picture is superimposed is used in the program quite often and the picture should have different shades depending on the logic. The image is now yellow, then green, and other shades.
And there are a LOT of shades. The easiest way to do this is simply to create images of different shades in advance and load them into memory. But uploading a lot of pictures will greatly increase the size of the application, and I would not want this. I tried this in Photoshop. I put a layer on top of the image and filled it with a solid color. Lowered the opacity of this layer. The result is a picture that looks like what I want. Therefore, the question is: how to create a **Bitmap** from another ready-made **Bitmap** and some color with transparency.

I need a method to which I send **Bitmap**, color, transparency level; and get a ready-made **Bitmap** of a changed shade from it. Can you tell me how can I achieve this result? How to overlay color on **Bitmap**?

Comment: `Bitmap bmp1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(cont.getResources(), R.drawable.image);`
//then create a copy of bitmap bmp1 into bmp2
`Bitmap bmp2 = bmp1.copy(bmp1.getConfig(), true);`

Comment: @  EAS, I made a copy of the Bitmap, but it's the same as the first one. How can I get a corrected Bitmap?

Comment: did you want like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4354939/understanding-the-use-of-colormatrix-and-colormatrixcolorfilter-to-modify-a-draw)